# Why does my jmeter script that work on a windows machine but comes back with org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException in linux?

Tags: jmeter

This is a high frequency error with occurrence more than 70% that a specific call comes back with **org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException**. However, same script didn't give me any issues when I executed it from Windows machine.

But once I set the advanced settings of http request with client implementation set to Java, that call responded with correct response and the mentioned exception never occurred again in linux.

**What could be the possible reason for this?**

I am using JMeter 5.4.1
Environment of execution is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to state anything without seeing trace (i.e. from [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) tool) for successful request and for the failed request, preferably from both Windows and Linux machines.

If you cannot take the network dump (i.e. you don't have sufficient permissions) you can try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity for the HttpComponents](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

this way you will be able to see request and response details in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If the following [limitations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) of `Java` implementation don't have impact on your test:

```
There is no control over how connections are re-used. When a connection is released by JMeter, it may or may not be re-used by the same thread.
The API is best suited to single-threaded usage - various settings are defined via system properties, and therefore apply to all connections.
No support of Kerberos authentication
It does not support client based certificate testing with Keystore Config.
Better control of Retry mechanism
It does not support virtual hosts.
It supports only the following methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and TRACE
Better control on DNS Caching with DNS Cache Manager
```

just proceed with this.